# Get absolute url in middleware using controllername, actionname and id

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, middleware

```
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {                
        var controllers = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetTypes().Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type) || type.Name.EndsWith("controller")).ToList();
            foreach (var controller in controllers)
            {
                var methods = controller.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).Where(method => typeof(IActionResult).IsAssignableFrom(method.ReturnType));
                foreach (var method in methods)
                {
```

I need to get absolute url here to use it in xml sitemap.

All my controllers and actions have custom route value using route attribute

Thank you!

Comment: Is this MVC? If so, have a look at [SimpleMvcSitemap](https://github.com/uhaciogullari/SimpleMvcSitemap) instead.

Comment: Yes, it is. But I want to build my own. I am beginner to asp.net and I want to learn